# Concatenating last 2 strings in a for loop

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
  for i in range(0, len(data), 4096):
     data_group = data[i: i+4096]
     if i == len(data) - 8193:
         data_group_second_last = data_group 
         print(data_group_second_last)
     if i==len(data) - 4097:
         data_group += data_group_second_last
     return data_group
```

I am iterating over some data with a 4096 bytes step. I am trying to concatenate the data strings from only the last 2 iterations of the for loop. What I have above doesn't work because the `len(data)` is not going to be in perfect multiples of 4096 so substracting that number from length won't work out.

Note: I need to use the loop to iterate through the data as I am decompressing along the way (can't decompress it if I seek to somewhere in the data).

Comment: What are ```str_chunk_last``` and ```str_chunk```?

Comment: @ewong rectified it.

Comment: Do you actually need to process other parts of the string (other than the last two chunks) in the loop?

Comment: @qrsngky It'd be nice if I can do 2 chunks at a time, but last two chunks work as well.

Comment: This returns on the first iteration. This doesn't loop.

Comment: @Rahul Is it different from iterating with steps of 8192 bytes?

Comment: @qrsngky it's not different than that.

Comment: @gre_gor you're right, I missed an if loop that actually does some logic and then returns the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate to find the last two chunks.  Just do some math:

```py
def last_two(data):
    full_chunks, remainder = divmod(len(data), 4096)
    return data[(full_chunks - (1 if remainder else 2)) * 4096:]
```

This will return the last two full chunks if length of data is a multiple of 4096, or the last chunk and remainder if not an even multiple of 4096.

Comment: Hey Mark, 

I need to iterate through the loop, I am iterating because this data is compressed and I can't decompress it if I seek to a point in the data. Also, I am chunking to avoid memory issues. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Rahul You can still compute the offsets to check for if you know the length of the data (as your code implies)

Comment: Yes sir, was just pointing out something that I had missed.